# Is it possible to create a single page application using MongoDB as a backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use the new single page application project from the upcoming Visual studio and I was wondering if it would be possible to create an application using a MongoDB backend for the DBContext. It seems that the upshot.js library relies heavily on this (for the metadata for inst , for the DBDataController, ...)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MongoDB does not have wrappers/support for the entity framework nor the [DBContext interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).  MongoDB can't be used as the backend for the Entity Framework.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798304/entity-framework-and-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

You cant use MongoDB with entity. But for one page application you can use [MongoRepository](http://mongorepository.codeplex.com/)
It's perfect to do something very fast and not to spend time on mongoDb implimantation.

Comment: Yes but the main purpose of using Entity is to be able to use upshot.js to manage the state of the data store on the client side.

Comment: oh, i see i didnt get ur question quite right.
But try to look here [link](http://css.dzone.com/articles/upshotjs-knockoutjs-html5) they use upshot.riaDataProvider and method that return IQurable. It is easy to implement with MongoDb.